# Compare between input value and typed text

Tags: javascript

I'm searching a way to compare a value from input and the typed text into the same input.

example : input value = aaabbb.
In the same input I add the letter c : aaabbbc

then if value is different to typed text I'm executing instructions.

```html
<input type="text" name="something" value="aaabbb"/>
```

I tried something like that but that does not work

```js
if(elemSrc.value!=this.value){    // elemSrc.value = aaabbb, this.value=typed text            
  document.getElementsByName('actionSave')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Not enough context provided.

Comment: I've got a value into input and when u type something into this input, it remove disabled from a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm searching a way to compare a value from input and the typed text
>   into the same input.

You could make use of `Element.value` to do the comparison (this will change in real time), whereas [`Element.getAttribute("value")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) would remain the same.

Here is a sample snippet to demonstrate the same:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var inputObj = document.querySelector("#TextInput");
  var inputValue = inputObj.getAttribute("value");
  console.log("Input value: " + inputValue);

  inputObj.onchange = function() {
    var currentValue = inputObj.value;
    if (currentValue != inputValue) {
      console.log("Typed Value: " + currentValue);
      // Do something.
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Original" id="TextInput" />
```

Comment: U got this, but it's normal that it takes a lot of time?

Comment: Regarding time - It depends on how complex your codebase is, you might want to use the right selector, and in the right place.

Comment: I finally delete the onchange and it works, thanks! :)